# How to call angular2 material design methods from external component

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material2

I am using angular2 material design side-nav component and I want to trigger the `toggle` from another component.

Template snippet for side-nav

```
<md-sidenav-container class="side-nav-open">
  <md-sidenav #sidenav mode="side" opened="true">
    <div class="">
      <li><a class="" [routerLink]="['/dataSelector']">Link One</a>
      </li>
    </div>
  </md-sidenav>
  <div id="dataDisplayContainer" class="dataDisplayContainer float-left">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</md-sidenav-container>
```

Template snippet of the header

```
<button md-button class="header-menu-button" (click)="sidenav.toggle()">
 <md-icon>menu</md-icon>
</button>
```

In the angular2 material example the side-nav have triggering button inside the directive

```
<md-sidenav #sidenav mode="side" opened="true">
    <button (click)="sidenav.toggle()">
      <md-icon>add</md-icon>
    </button>
    <div class="example-scrolling-content">Content</div>
  </md-sidenav>
```

But In my case the triggering button is outside the directive.What I am trying to do is on click of the button located in header it will toggle the side nav.
[image]

Comment: how are the components linked? update the parent component to the post

Comment: @Aravind components have no relation neither child,parent or siblings

Comment: the `button and sidenav`  are in different components you mentioned.

Comment: @Aravind let me take back my word, I will rather say they are sibling component

Comment: making use of event emitters might solve the issue you can set a `output emitter ` and listen  for it in the parent

Comment: @brk can you post your markup? If they are siblings this shouldn't be too difficult either through a template ref or using the parent component.